# OnException method is never ran

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-filters

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app. Using the following, my `OnException` method is never ran (I can't break point it and throwing an uncaught exception doesn't do anything either so I am assuming it is never run)

```
using Elmah;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace App.WebUI
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }

    public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            // Log only handled exceptions, because all other will be caught by ELMAH anyway.
            if (context.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my global.asx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace App.WebUI
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Don't you need to extend FilterAttribute class also?

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it and it made no difference. I am not ever using it as an attribute [in squared brackets] this is the only place I am using it, I want it to be global so it runs every time an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Make sure you've enabled custom errors in root web.config.

```
<system.web>
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error"
                    mode="On">

      </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

After doing this I've verified in my local ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter.OnException executed.

I've explicitly throwing exception from controller to test functionality.

Below is my code:

TestController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            throw new Exception("gone!");
}
```

FilterConfig.cs

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
        public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter
        {
            public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
            {
                // Log only handled exceptions, because all other will be caught by ELMAH anyway.
                //it is true
                if (context.ExceptionHandled)
                {
                    var dsf=context.ExceptionHandled;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have just copied over that code into my web.config and it still isn't running. The line in the command still isn't being ran (none of my breakpoints in the function are being hit).